# Abort child workflow by a trigger

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, parent-child, state-machine

I am executing dynamically loaded child work-flows by a parent workflow. while the child workflow is executing I want to abort the current child workflow and start a new workflow from dynamically loaded file (.xaml) according to the user inputs from the parent workflow.
My parent workflow is a state machine which is exposed as a service and it has a state which executes another loaded child workflow in the entry method of the state (using Microsoft.Activities.Extensions ).I want child workflow to be changed according to a trigger. Child workflow can be a state machine or sequential .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways a workflow can be aborted.

1. The host WorkflowApplication
2. The workflow itself can use the Terminate activity

In your case, Microsoft.Activities.Extensions uses a WorkflowInvoker to invoke the workflow and you cannot abort the child workflow so your only option is to have the child workflow check for some kind of a "signal" to terminate if it is looping.

This "signal" could be the presence of a file, record in a database etc.

Comment: What I want to do is to stop the child workflow by a external trigger (A WCF call to parent workflow). Let's say my child workflow is also a state machine and I want to change the state to final state in the child workflow by the parent. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible - but you will need two transitions off of every state that you want to be able to exit from. So, let's say you have a few states and then a final state - in every state in which you need to be able to abort you will need to have at least two triggers. One will have a Receive in the trigger (this is the entry point you call to stop the workflow) and the others will be for processing. However, the others MUST implement something that will issue a bookmark so that the Receive can be reached! So go with @RonJacobs approach here I think.

Comment: Because Microsoft.Activities.Extensions uses WorkflowInvoker to invoke the child workflow you cannot use receive activities or bookmarks.  The child workflow has to be something that can be run by WorkflowInvoker.  If you need something more complex you will have to create a more advanced version of InvokeWorkflow based on WorkflowApplication - this will get tricky.  Might be better to stick with messaging between the parent workflow and child workflow.

Comment: Ok. Let's say my child workflow is a state machine and the signal is in a database record. In that case I have to have a trigger in all states to final state as @mperrenoud03 said. And the other thing is even though the database entry is changed how the trigger in the child knows that? Then I need to periodicity check the database ? Or else can I expose my child workflow as a service to external(not through the parent) call?

Comment: My apologies, I missed the fact that you're children were XAML files and not XAMLX. And remember, always follow @RonJacobs anyway considering who he is. Ron - my apologies for looking as if I was going against your direction.

Comment: I will check the database flag in each and every trigger. And use the terminate activity to terminate the workflow. Is it a good approach to handle huge number of workflows?

Comment: @mperrenoud03 yes I have to follow him anyway :P . I thought he also misunderstood me.